# Is this the correct use of sklearn classification report for multi-label classification reports?

Tags: keras, scikit-learn, multilabel-classification, precision-recall

I am training a neural network with tf-keras. It is a multi-label classification where each sample belongs to multiple classes [1,0,1,0..etc] .. the final model line (just for clarity) is:

```
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(9, activation='sigmoid'))#final layer

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, 
                metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy(), 
                tfa.metrics.F1Score(num_classes=9, average='macro',threshold=0.5)])
```

I need to generate precision, recall and F1 scores for these (I already get the F1 score reported during training). For this I am using sklearns classification report, but I need to confirm that I am using it correctly in the multi-label setting.

```
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report

pred = model.predict(x_test)
pred_one_hot = np.around(pred)#this generates a one hot representation of predictions

print(classification_report(one_hot_ground_truth, pred_one_hot))
```

This works fine and i get the full report for every class including F1 scores that match the F1score metric from tensorflow addons (for macro F1). Sorry this post is verbose but what I am unsure about is:

Is it correct that the predictions need to be one-hot encoded in the case of the multi-label setting? If I pass in the normal prediction scores (sigmoid probabilities) an error is thrown...

thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is correct to use `classification_report` for both binary, multi-class  and multi-label classification.

The labels are not one-hot-encoded in case of multi-class classification. They simply need to be either `indices` or `labels`.

You can see that both code below yield the same output:

**Example with indices**

```
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
import numpy as np

labels = np.array(['A', 'B', 'C'])


y_true = np.array([1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0])
y_pred = np.array([1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0])
print(classification_report(y_true, y_pred, target_names=labels))
```

**Example with labels**

```
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
import numpy as np

labels = np.array(['A', 'B', 'C'])

y_true = labels[np.array([1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0])]
y_pred = labels[np.array([1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0])]
print(classification_report(y_true, y_pred))
```

Both returns

```
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

           A       1.00      0.50      0.67         2
           B       0.50      1.00      0.67         2
           C       1.00      0.50      0.67         2

    accuracy                           0.67         6
   macro avg       0.83      0.67      0.67         6
weighted avg       0.83      0.67      0.67         6
```

In the context of multi-label classification, `classification_report` can be used like in the example below:

```
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
import numpy as np

labels =['A', 'B', 'C']

y_true = np.array([[1, 0, 1],
                   [0, 1, 0],
                   [1, 1, 1]])
y_pred = np.array([[1, 0, 0],
                   [0, 1, 1],
                   [1, 1, 1]])

print(classification_report(y_true, y_pred, target_names=labels))
```

Comment: thank you - and what about for the multi-label case? are one-hot labels acceptable? - and if not, what is the correct way in which the multi labels should be supplied? the sklearn documentatio suggest this is the correct way, but it isnt 100% clear to me

Comment: I edited my question with an example on how to use `classification_report` for multi-label case.

Comment: great thank you! yes this clarifies it - and just one last quesation- each row = 1 sample correct?.. so for y_true, [1,0,1] = sample 1 -- [0,1,0] = sample 2 and [1,1,1] = sample 3?

Comment: Yes, every row in y_true and y_pred correspond to 1 sample.

Comment: perfect - thank you for confirming. answer accepted :)